# Dynamic SQL un dynamic PL/SQL example

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am a beginner, can you please briefly and without using complex constructions show an example of a PL/SQL program where dynamic SQL and dynamic PL/SQL is used? can there be one PL/SQL program that uses both dynamic SQL  and dynamic PL/SQL at the same time?

Comment: This is not really the forum for this type of help. Try searching for an online tutorial

Comment: There is no useful information, everything is very complicated.

Comment: You probably find it “very complicated” because you are a self-confessed beginner and are trying to run before you can walk. If you spend some time getting a solid understanding of the basics of SQL and some real world experience then more advanced  topics like pl/sql and dynamic sql will probably make more sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are.

- `l_sql` is a local variable which contains a simple SQL statement - it creates a table
- `l_plsql` then contains an anonymous PL/SQL block which - in a loop - insert several rows into previously (dynamically) created table

---

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_sql   varchar2(1000);
  3    l_plsql varchar2(1000);
  4  begin
  5    l_sql := 'create table t_sql (id number)';
  6
  7    l_plsql := 'begin ' ||
  8               '  for i in 1 .. 5 loop ' ||
  9               '    insert into t_sql (id) values (i); ' ||
 10               '  end loop; ' ||
 11               'end;';
 12
 13    execute immediate l_sql;
 14    execute immediate l_plsql;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t_sql;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5

SQL>
```